# calculation with php is not working

Tags: php

In php I want some calculation part to be done. So I am getting all the values from variable and doing calculation. When doing calculation my formula is something like this

```
ceil($99.00/100)*2
```

but here it is showing error as $(dollar currency symbol is there). So can someone kindly tell me what is the good method of doing calculation here?

Comment: What is the $ for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: drop the $. Ceiling takes the next whole integer up if there is a decimal. Example 100.01 will become 101. Floor does the opposite, would be 100

Answer (score 6):

You need to learn [basic PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). You can't feed a monetary string (99 dollars and zero cents) into math operation. PHP will attempt to use `$99` as a variable, and variables cannot be named with numbers.

You're basically doing

```
ceil (99 dollars concatenated with (zero divided by one hundred)) times two
```

If you're trying to do actual math with numbers, then

```
ceil(99/100) * 2
```

is all you'd need.

Comment: so what is the solution for it?

Comment: @NewUser It's simple (and a little obvious): drop the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are dividing 99 dollars 0 cents with one hundred and multiplying the result by 2.

Try this:

```
<?php
$amount = 99.00;

$calculation = ($amount/100)*2;

echo $calculation;
```

You should append the dollar sign after you have done the calculation. Like this:

```
echo '$'.$calculation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $. PHP can't calculate with anything but pure numbers, so `$99.00` obviously won't work for 99 dollars.

Actually, what PHP thinks you are trying to do is have a variable (variable names start with a `$`). But `99` is not a valid variable name. Then PHP thinks you want to concatenate that variable with the result of `0 / 100` (concatenation is done with `.`.